# PDO last insert id return 0

Tags: php, pdo, last-insert-id

Am facing in problem with last insert id, this is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (                                     
          `id` int(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                   
          `fbtoken_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,                 
          `user_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,                  
          `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,                           
          `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,                        
          `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,                        
          `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,                       
          `fbuserid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,                   
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                     
          KEY `id` (`id`)                                         
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  

$stmt = $this->core->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user(fbtoken_id,user_name,email,city,created,modified,fbuserid)
VALUES(:fbtoken_id,:first_name,:email,:location,:created,:modified,:fbuserid)");

$stmt->execute(array(':fbtoken_id' => $access_token, ':first_name' => $first_name, ':email' => $email, ':location' => $location,
':created' => $datetime, ':modified' => $datetime,':fbuserid' => $fbuserid));

$_SESSION['userid']=$this->core->dbh->lastInsertId();
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
echo 'userid', $_SESSION['userid'];
```

Here am setting the last insert id to session and using user id for all his transactions. In my local testing am getting the last insert id correctly. everything works perfect. But when i upload my code to server, at some point of time the session is not setting or the last insert id is getting 0. I don't understand how to replicate the issue in live server.

Is it the correct way to use last insertid or any other alternative to get new user id ?

I saw in some cases to use

```
$this->core->dbh->beginTransaction();
  last insert id 
$this->core->dbh->commit();
```

Is this code needed ?

Please help me to debug the situation. Thanks in advance

//Edit

```
$stmt = $this->core->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user(fbtoken_id,user_name,email,city,created,modified,fbuserid)
VALUES(:fbtoken_id,:first_name,:email,:location,:created,:modified,:fbuserid)");
$this->core->dbh->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute(array(':fbtoken_id' => $access_token, ':first_name' => $first_name, ':email' => $email, ':location' => $location,
':created' => $datetime, ':modified' => $datetime,':fbuserid' => $fbuserid));

$_SESSION['userid']=$this->core->dbh->lastInsertId();
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
echo 'userid', $_SESSION['userid'];
 $this->core->dbh->commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Last insert ID will not work after a commit - it needs to be executed before the commit happens. edited because finger slipped. So if you want to use lastinsert id - you need to control the transaction within code.

Comment: I read the manual but here am not using  commit(), without commit am getting the correct last insert id. I also tried with commit(). I used commit() after fetching last insert id. It was also working correctly.

Comment: you mean locally, and it didn't work once on the server?

Comment: Its working in local server, i never faced any problem, in live its also working. But for some users when i checked in db their session id is 0. I cannot replicate the issue yet ? is it the problem with the session or last inser id ?

Comment: I'm thinking without being wrapped in a transaction, it's all in the air: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Comment: I have edited my question to include begin transaction and commit. Is it ok ?

Comment: you could move  $this->core->dbh->commit(); higher up, right after you get the lasinsertid, but yes - you've got the gist of it there

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions, i will test my code with this modifications..